# Keyboard issues with Mathematica 9.0.1 for Linux

Tags: notebooks, keyboard, kernel, linux

After working for a while with [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) function and increasing the number of variables to be manipulated, keyboard stops working properly in the Notebook. It gets really crazy, mainly the keys <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd>. For example,  some times <kbd>Backspace</kbd> starts behaving as the <kbd>Left</kbd> Key, some times as <kbd>Right</kbd>, etc. all this randomly. 
I am running *Mathematica* for Linux, and I have had this issue with Ubuntu 13.04 and recently with Ubuntu 13.10 as well.
This is not an issue related to my computer since outside *Mathematica* the keyboard works as usual.

Comment: Googling "keyboard issues ubuntu" yields many problems with the latest releases. My guess is that this is probably not related to Mathematica.

Comment: I have experienced the same issue where the keyboard keys get randomly remapped all of a sudden (when doing heavy computation).  I don't think it's the `Manipulate` function that is causing the problem since I'm not using that.  For me, it's also the letter keys that get randomly remapped, for example, `F` was remapped to `Left` key.  (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, Macbook Pro, Mathematica v 9.0.0).

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with Ubuntu because I can switch back and forth between Mathematica and Gedit and it works fine in Gedit.

Comment: I have this remapping issue on windows 8 too.

Comment: Have you reported this problem to WRI?  Did you receive any reply or follow-up?

Comment: I have the same issue, though it starts randomly, heavy computations are not needed to trigger it. I'm now using Ubuntu 14.04 and it has increased in frequency. very bizarre.

Comment: I also am experiencing the same problem with Mathematica 9.0 as well as Mathematica 10.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. It is definitely related to Mathematica and not Ubuntu in general. My current "solution" is to restart Mathematica.

Comment: Just one more "me too" here: I have this problem in Mathematica 10.0 on Ubuntu 15.04. It is a really bizarre and maddening bug.

Comment: Switching to gnome seems to have fixed it.